# How to configure yugabytedb for strict serialization?

Tags: yugabytedb

It is understood from dbmsmusings portal that financial transactions require strict serialization and non-adherence will lead to anomalies.

Please guide me in configuring yugabytedb for strict serialization and also it's cost on performance and/or functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YugabyteDB [supports](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/transactions/isolation-levels/) `snapshot isolation` and `serializable isolation`.

1 way is to set isolation level on [`BEGIN`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ysql/commands/txn_begin/#transaction-mode) :

```
yb_demo=# begin transaction isolation level serializable;
BEGIN
yb_demo=# SHOW transaction_isolation;
 transaction_isolation 
-----------------------
 serializable
(1 row)

yb_demo=# commit;
COMMIT
yb_demo=# SHOW transaction_isolation;
 transaction_isolation 
-----------------------
 read committed
(1 row)
```

Another way is using [`SET TRANSACTION`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ysql/commands/txn_set/) statement:

```
yb_demo=# begin;
BEGIN
yb_demo=# SHOW transaction_isolation;
 transaction_isolation 
-----------------------
 read committed
(1 row)

yb_demo=# SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL serializable;
SET
yb_demo=# SHOW transaction_isolation;
 transaction_isolation 
-----------------------
 serializable
(1 row)

yb_demo=# commit;
COMMIT
```